# Problems with C# internet connection

Tags: c#, sockets

i'm trying to make an application for my laptop which in case i forgot to log off, i can use my smarthphone to log off by using a specific app for that. So i was thinking usually if you have a router... you have a problem cause you don't have the external ip which you can use, and the port. For that i used this function to get the external ip.

```
        public string adresaIP()
    {
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        WebClient clientWeb = new WebClient();
        String adresaIP = utf8.GetString(clientWeb.DownloadData("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com"));
        return adresaIP;
    }
```

But when i try to use te IpEndPoint it dosen't work it give's me an exception Error and i don't know were i did wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;


namespace bluetooth_LogOff
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static byte[] buffer { get; set; }
    static Socket soket;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            string ip = adresaIP();

            soket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            //soket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip),1234)); <<-- in this way dosen't work 

            soket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),1234)); // <<- in this way it works....
            soket.Listen(100);


            Socket accept = soket.Accept();
            buffer = new byte[accept.SendBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = accept.Receive(buffer);
            byte[] format = new byte[bytesRead];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                format[i] = buffer[i];
            }
            string primescMesaj = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(format);
            MessageBox.Show(primescMesaj);
            soket.Close();
            accept.Close();



        }
        catch (Exception messaj)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(messaj.ToString());

        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Text = adresaIP();





    }
    public string adresaIP()
    {
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        WebClient clientWeb = new WebClient();
        String adresaIP =    `utf8.GetString(clientWeb.DownloadData("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com"));`
        return adresaIP;
    }
}

}
```

But the funny thing is if i put the addres like "127.0.0.1" It works, but if i put the string addres it dosen't

Comment: What type of exception?

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  Exceptions have a long history of providing useful information.

Comment: Hello thank you for the quick response here is the pic [link]http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/534/asdsadasddasdsadsa.png/[/link]

Comment: @MirceaMihai: 1) There's no picture at that link.  2) We're not looking for pictures, just information about the error(s) and runtime behavior you're experiencing which indicates that something's wrong.

Comment: There was a picture (just remove the [/link]).  I use TcpClient it works well for me

Comment: This is the message i receive -> system.net.socketsexception (0x8004005): The requested address is not valid in its context it's a bit longer i can put it all of it if i have too

Comment: @MirceaMihai yes, edit your post to reflect the error for future viewers who might search for that error, but my answer is still correct :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot bind to the external address that address belongs to the router.

You should bind to address 0.0.0.0 (all addresses) on your laptop and configure your router to forward the laptop port (or use UPnP).

The reason you cannot access your laptop directly is because your router, like most routers is a NAT (network address translation) router. It allows several computers to hide behind a single IP address. So the router will have a public IP address and your laptop and other devices behind the router will have a private IP address (such as those in the range 192.168.x.x)

Most NAT routers can be configured with static port forwarding; i.e. the port in a specific private address is reflected in the same or a different port in the public IP.
This allows access to internal devices from the public internet. UPnP is a protocol that does the same thing, but does not require manual configuration on the router. UPnP is usually how P2P applications and some multi-player games gain public accessible ports without human intervention. It is also why UPnP may be considered a security hazard since the computer owner may not be aware of such forwarding.

Comment: I never thought of that, i will try as soon as i get home. You're right here i have router here and probably that could be.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but then i wonder how can i manage to log off my pc behind a router without the intervention of port forwarding or other thing like that?

Comment: @MirceaMihai: If you want to remotely connect to something that's behind a router then you either need the router to forward connections to it or you need the machine to actively be connected to an external service to which you would then remotely connect.  It's not "intervention" it's just how networks work.  A computer needs to be able to send messages to another computer in order for that other computer to receive them.

Comment: Hmmm what if i install on my laptop no-ip.org application ? Can i bind somehow to the no-ip address? And after that if i send message, i send it straight to the no-ip address which i have.

Comment: @MirceaMihai If you don't want to use port forwarding and have the laptop directly accessible. You can use an indirect form of command: send an email to a special email address and have a service on your laptop pool that email periodically (every 1-5 minutes) or leave a special file in a service like dropbox or google drive and act when it gets synced to your laptor.

Comment: @MirceaMihai no-ip is not going to help that is merely a dynamic dns which will point to the public address owned by the router. There is no way around it: your private address is not accessible from the public internet; either you write a program that uses some form of port forwarding or pool a public repository (email, dropbox, etc.) to pass messages.

Comment: Hmmm that could be a good idea. You're saying something like this -> on my smarthphone i put a file -> Log-Off-NOW = 1 (if it's 1 it will log off else it will not log off).  But then i have antoher problem, how do i make an app for my smarthphone to put a file in there, or change the values from 0 to 1 ?

Comment: @MirceaMihai I'm no expert in smartphone apps, but I believe there is an API for that. Email should be easier. Just set up a free account with imapi or pop4 support just for your service and have it check it every few minutes (C# has libraries for accessing mail with these protocols). Then you don't need a smartphone app, just send an email with subject log-off and a password (so other people don't just loh you off by sending emails). The service will know to log you off if the email is new (unread), and it can then be deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, i will try to see hope it's going to work well.